# Как получить id и класс по нажатию на элемент?

Tags: jquery

Есть короче вкладки с категориями, есть слайдер постов определенных категории.
Пока что он выводит посты всех категории везде. Я нажимаю на ссылку "читать далее" открывается слайдер с инфой и наверху показано , что видно и можно посмотреть 10 постов , а в это категории всего их 5. Я хочу чтобы 5 и показало. Я понял что с вкладками гиблое дело, поэтому решил , что когда нажимаю на "читать далее" то получаю его класс , а в этом классе имя категории. Просто он показывает именно то , что ты ему подаешь. Если подать класс `dsfdsf` то он и покажет все посты связанные с этим классом

```
a class="CATEGORYaaa post_link"
```

хочу передать этот класс в функцию и вывести все нужные посты. Чтобы я мог пролистать только эти 5 постов. Я попытался сделать вот так (внизу код) чтобы получить только первый класс и вставить. Теперь всё работает , нажимаю на "читать далее" в первый раз, то контент не появляется, а когда нажимаю второй, то тогда загружает . Но почему только со второго раза ? (ajax функция внизу)

```
  $(function(){
 $('a').click(function(){
 classs =$(this).attr('class').split(' ', 1)[0];
 alert(classs);
  $("."+classs)
  .attr('rel', 'gallery')
  .fancybox({
      type: 'iframe',
      autoSize : false
  })


  });
 });


  $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $(".post-link").click(function(){
        var post_link = $(this).attr("href");

        $(".containerr").html("content loading");
        $(".containerr").load(post_link);
    return false;
    });
```

Comment: Т.е. надо по сути применить некие колдунства к элементу на который, собссно, тыцнули?

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Посмотрите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Сперва получаем id и записываем его в переменную:

```
var id = '#';
$('li').click(function(){
    id += $(this).attr('id');
});
```

А потом где надо вставляем его:

```
$(id)
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
  .fancybox({
      type: 'iframe',
      autoSize : false
  });
```

Или можно совместить, тут уж в зависимости где и как вы используете его.

**UPD**

```
$('a').click(function(){
   classs =$(this).attr('class').split(' ', 1)[0];
   $("."+classs)
   .attr('rel', 'gallery')
   .fancybox({
       type: 'iframe',
       autoSize : false
   })
   if ($(this).hasClass('post-link')) {
      $(".containerr").html("content loading").load($(this).attr("href"));
   }
});
```

Comment: $("#" + id)...{...}

Comment: Попытался я прописать . Всё равно как то не получается передать , так как на работает вывод в слайдер . Обновил код в вопросе

Comment: @NikitaKurilovic так ваша функция срабатывает только один раз - в момент загрузки, когда id пустой `""`. А когда при клике его значение меняется - это значение уже не попадает в слайдер. Можно попробовать содержимое второй функции полностью перенести в функцию `.click(function{ // туда })`. Чтобы всё происходило после клика.

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: @NikitaKurilovic полагаю, это из-за того, что вы на ссылку 2 события вешаете сразу

Comment: @InDevX  а как можно сделать по другому ?

Comment: @NikitaKurilovic добавил в ответ

Comment: @InDevX не помогло. Всё равно с первого раза нажимаю , мне показывает, что всё плохо, а второй раз уже загружает контент

Comment: @NikitaKurilovic можете выложить работающий код? чтоб можно было увидеть проблему

Comment: @InDevX Очень много php , поэтому с этим проблема. Я хотел закинуть в песочницу, но не могу. Всё берётся из базы данных (этот весь контент, когда нажимаешь читать далее и тд) Почти всё с пхп. Просто , если без этой системы, что я придумал , то всё открывается с первого раза. Есть раздел "все категории" и там этой системы по классам нету , там он всё берёт с одного класса ```.fancybox``` и всё открывается с первого раза. А вот тут открывает, показывает , что контента нет, закрываешь , открываешь и контент появляется

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('ul li').on('click', function () {
  $(this)
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
      type: 'iframe',
      autoSize : false
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.min.js" integrity="sha256-yt2kYMy0w8AbtF89WXb2P1rfjcP/HTHLT7097U8Y5b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.min.css" integrity="sha256-Vzbj7sDDS/woiFS3uNKo8eIuni59rjyNGtXfstRzStA=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Посмотрите, пожалуйста